# Is it possible to run angular2 and javabackend code in the same webcontainer

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web-content

Is it possible to run angular2 and javabackend code in the same webcontainer?? If yes then please mention how. Thanks.

Comment: Angular is Javascript, so it doesn't run in a Java webcontainer. Can you please clarify, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to make sure that when I call the backend call I dont have to mention the domain(ip and port) of the backend server where the application is running.

Answer (score 1):

In your case Angular application is a client side app, that is not dependant on any server side applications, so it`s only possible to develop the java apllication as a server and the angular application as a client separately.

Comment: and then how angular application will call the servlet?

Comment: The angular app is a client, which listens to it's port on it's address. It just gets requests from user and delivers them to the server (which is another separate app and can be hosted on the other address and listens to the other port). To be short angular app is something like Postman, it`s just sends the request to API, but it may have some extra logic and functionality and is hosted separately. You can even have as many different client applications, which call the same server, as you want